# runtime error in android devices

Tags: java, android

I have created an app and it runs successfully in the emulator. When I was trying to run it in any of my devices it shows the following error:

```
[2011-02-12 09:57:06 - FirstImage] Android Launch!
[2011-02-12 09:57:06 - FirstImage] adb is running normally.
[2011-02-12 09:57:06 - FirstImage] Performing com.gis.image.FirstImage activity launch
[2011-02-12 09:57:23 - FirstImage] Uploading FirstImage.apk onto device 'HT96WKF01291'
[2011-02-12 09:57:32 - FirstImage] Installing FirstImage.apk...
[2011-02-12 09:57:52 - FirstImage] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-02-12 09:57:52 - FirstImage] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-02-12 09:57:52 - FirstImage] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.gis.image' in a shell.
[2011-02-12 09:57:52 - FirstImage] Launch canceled!
```

What is the issue and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Well, did you try to perform "adb uninstall com.gis.image"?

Comment: no i dint and i dont know how to do it. pls help me in thta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed this .apk before, and it was compiled using a different signature (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) for details).  To fix this you need to remove the previous installation (you have to do that only when the signature has changed - not normally).

On the device itself, go Menu->Settings->Manage Applications. Select the application which you want to Uninistall, and click on the ‘Uninstall’ button.  Now try your install.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the application directly from eclipse it is signed by a different certificate than the one you use when you create the application for market.

What is most likely happening is that you have the app installed with a different signature than the one you are trying to install now.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this happens, when you keep on installing the app through your code then it sometimes gives such kind of error..To over come this Just Open a terminal And paste this

> adb uninstall com.gis.image

This is according to your Above error log...

You Just need to Uninstall your app from the Device.. Just like it :)

Hope this Helps....